# DISCORD.JS restart shard when dies

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to have my shard automatically reconnect when it disconnects? Thanks.

```
const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js')
const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', { token: "TOKEN"})

manager.on('shardCreate', shard => {
    console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`)
    shard.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Shard ready')
    })
    shard.on('disconnect', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard disconnected')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    shard.on('reconnecting', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard reconnecting')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    shard.on('death', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard died')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
})
manager.spawn()
```

My bot randomly crashes it's shards during the night, so I am asking if I can have the shards automatically respawn when it dies. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Case, I guess you can have crashed Shards Respawn by using the Following:

```
const manager = new ShardingManager('BOT_FILE_HERE', {
    token: "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE",
    respawn: true,
})
```

I hope this helps you just as much as it has helped me.

Comment: i figured it out, it was a RAM issue.